Color not changing on theme change
I am not getting the desired output. I am trying to code a small task.The task is that I want to change the color of the screen background, the text and the button as shown in the uploaded image.There are total 3 files of the code. The index one, the one that contains the custom hook and the css file. I am uploading all of them. The commands change in the local storage upon pressing of "change theme" button but the changes don't reflect on screen. I am attaching the code. Please answer if you now what's the problem:
[enter image description here][1]

 index.jsx file:

import useLocalStorage from "./useLocalStorage";

export default function DarkWhiteTheme() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useLocalStorage("theme", "dark");

  const handleToggleTheme = () => {
    setTheme(theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light");
  };

  console.log(theme);

  return (
    <div className="light-dark-mode" data-theme={theme}>
      <div className="container">
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <button onClick={handleToggleTheme} className="change-theme-button">
          Change Theme
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


 useLocalStorage File:


export default function useLocalStorage(key, defaultValue) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    let currentValue;
    try {
      currentValue = JSON.parse(
        localStorage.getItem(key) || String(defaultValue)
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      currentValue = defaultValue;
    }

    return currentValue;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [key, value]);

  return [value, setValue];
}


 style.css file


:root {
    --background : #ffffff
    --text-primary : #000000
    --button-bg: #000000
    --button-text: #ffffff
}

[data-theme='dark'] {
    --background: #000000
    --text-primary: #ffffff
    --button-bg: #ffffff
    --button-text: #000000
}

.light-dark-mode {
    background-color: var(--background);
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}

.light-dark-mode .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 30px;
}

.light-dark-mode .container p{
    color: var(--text-primary);
    font-size: 40px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.light-dark-mode .container button{
    background-color: var(--button-bg);
    border: 1px solid var(--button-bg);
    color: var(--button-text);
    padding: 12px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-weight: 600;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.change-theme-button{
    cursor: pointer;
}```


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/ed5hnovI.png


voting to close as typo.

Agree with @pilchard, voting to close as "not reproducible or was caused by typo".

Your code is all fine, there is nothing wrong with the useLocalStorage hook.  The issue is with your CSS.  You've forgotten a bunch of semi-colons.
change this:
:root {
    --background : #ffffff
    --text-primary : #000000
    --button-bg: #000000
    --button-text: #ffffff
}

[data-theme='dark'] {
    --background: #000000
    --text-primary: #ffffff
    --button-bg: #ffffff
    --button-text: #000000
}

to this

:root {
    --background : #ffffff;
    --text-primary : #000000;
    --button-bg: #000000;
    --button-text: #ffffff;
}

[data-theme='dark'] {
    --background: #000000;
    --text-primary: #ffffff;
    --button-bg: #ffffff;
    --button-text: #000000;
}


instead of
export default function useLocalStorage(key, defaultValue) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    let currentValue;
    try {
      currentValue = JSON.parse(
        localStorage.getItem(key) || String(defaultValue)
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      currentValue = defaultValue;
    }

    return currentValue;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
  }, [key, value]);

  return [value, setValue];
}

try
export default function useLocalStorage(key, defaultValue) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {
    const storedValue = localStorage.getItem(key);
    return storedValue !== null ? JSON.parse(storedValue) : defaultValue;
  });

  const setStoredValue = (newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(newValue));
  };

  return [value, setStoredValue];
}

this might help
